# parse xml for node value and save it as variable in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to save the value of `<Host></Host>` into a variable in my php and having issues. Lots of examples on here but none seem to help me with just a doing a single value and it confuses me.

```
 <CONFIG application="SAM" version="3.4.2">
    <Database>
            <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
            <Host>testdomain.com</Host>
            <Port>3306</Port>
            <Database>SAMDB2</Database>
            <Username>root</Username>
            <Password>xxxxx</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: What XML library are you attempting to use? SimpleXML is generally the easiest to begin with. Is this a component of a real, valid XML document (which would begin with `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`)?

Comment: simplexml is what i  use i just left out the top line sorry

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is very easy with SimpleXML:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<CONFIG application="SAM" version="3.4.2">
    <Database>
            <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
            <Host>testdomain.com</Host>
            <Port>3306</Port>
            <Database>SAMDB2</Database>
            <Username>root</Username>
            <Password>xxxxx</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
XML;

# load the string into simpleXML
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
# echo the host:
echo "Host: " . $sxe->Database->Host . PHP_EOL;

# echo the driver, port no., and database:
echo "Driver: " . $sxe->Database->Driver 
. "; Port: " . $sxe->Database->Port
. "; Database: " . $sxe->Database->Database . PHP_EOL;

# save the host as a object
$host = $sxe->Database->Host;
echo "\nhost object: ";
var_dump($host);

# save the host as a string
$host_str = (string)$sxe->Database->Host;
echo "\nhost string: ";
var_dump($host_str);
```

Output:

```
Host: testdomain.com
Driver: MYSQL Port: 3306; Database: SAMDB2

host object: class SimpleXMLElement#3 (1) {
  public ${0} =>
  string(14) "testdomain.com"
}

host string: string(14) "testdomain.com"
```